# Improve "today's orders" screen

Tags: actions, reports

I'm having problems on how to make one screen of my app user friendly;
the purpose of the screen is to display today's orders. It also has an option to choose another day.

So what I have now is a segmented button to switch between open and closed, and then at the right the list of items for that order.

The top right buttons are the invoices of the order (since there can be more than one) and the left button is to select a date.

Finally below there are actions (cancel order and reopen order) as well as the price totals.

How can I improve the design so that the relationship between the different sets of information is clear and the actions follow a logical flow for the user?

[image: Current layout]

Answer (score 1):

In general, it's not extremely bad, but I think the problem comes from your own choice of wording, which in terms makes everything more confusing.

First, what do "open" and "closed" mean? As an user, I really have no idea what you mean. I assume the English language has been added specifically for this question (if not, get rid of it *immediately*!) but shouldn't it be "PAID | UNPAID"?

Then, still in the left column, is it possible for you to categorize the invoices? I mean, I have no clue what the app is about, but assuming this is a general invoicing app, maybe you can name those invoices with categories like "Groceries" or even better, the name of the place where the purchase happened.

Now, on to the right column: is this Catalan (as your name implies) or just bad Spanish? If Spanish, the columns should be something like *"Seleccionar Fecha"*, *"Precio Unitario"* and *"Precio Total"*. Also, the *"Seleccionar una data"* link is out of place, because it's pointing to a column which has no dates at all, but product names. So make that link a `select` element and put it above everything.

Now, on to the bottom zone. Why are people re-opening orders? How do they know these orders are closed and what happened to those orders that are showing as closed? and why?

Also, if an order is closed, why are they cancelling it? If it's open, why are they re-opening? Is it possible for you to use just simple actions like "make purchase", "cancel purchase", and "save as draft"? (Or, if it is a pre-order process: "make order", "cancel - delete", "save".)

Bottom right: what are those numbers for? what do they mean? why is the first amount repeated? why the 0.00? is this a tax? a service fee? a tip? something else? You'll need to work this out as well, but quite probably you'll only need a *basic price*, whatever that *3.15 value* means and then *total price*.

This bottom part is absolutely unclear (and I speak Spanish), so you will need to figure the whole process, and maybe explain things a little better. For example, something you're leaving out of the picture (and the answer makes a massive difference): is this app to pre-order things, is this a list of already ordered items, is this a wishlist, a combination of these all, something else? The answer will change the whole UX flow.

Comment: Thank yo so much! the app is about a cloud POS for restaurants and bars so open orders actually means non paid :D the screenshot languages is catalan yeah.

Bottom part numbers are the totals (subtotal, discount, tax and total) so I think that the labels would help a lot there :D, 

The repoen button is needed in case the customer sees something wrong, they can reopen it, change and then do the refund or anything

Answer (score 1):

While my spanish is a bit rusty ;-) below are some recommendations to improve UX after a brief look at your question and image:

1. Keep the order breakdown list 'in-line' (i.e. when clicking on a specific order, the (item) breakdown will open under the order) so the eyes and mouse/hands do not need to move all over the screen.
2. Keeping the order breakdown 'in-line' will also remove a redundant listing of amount (67.95) since it will show in the order line right above the breakdown.
3. Any and all actions/links relevant to the order should also be 'in-line', again to make the flow efficient.
4. To avoid possible confusion in which list the user is, the default view should be 'open orders'...with a (smaller) link/button for 'closed orders' and when in 'closed orders' have a link/button for 'open orders'.

Happy to answer and advise on any further questions.
Good luck!

All the best,
Michael